# Page break doesn't work inside div. How do I add this tag?

Tags: html, css

The page-break-before doesn't work in any way. I included in different tags (div, p and h1) and added display block, but the display changes the layout. How can I add the page-break at the beginning?

I have tried to include page-break-before inside a div before the , and page-break-after the last div but it doesn't seem to work when I put the printing preview. All the pages that I did are the same as this code below.

```html
<h1 class="page-title" style="font-weight: 1000"><img width="6%" src="../../assets/admin/layout/img/icon_anamnese.png" alt="...">&nbsp;Anamnese</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="portlet-body">
      <div class="table-scrollable">
        <table class="table col-md-12">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: #8fc4c4 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-5 lead">Objetivos com relação à atividade física?</td>
              <td style="background-color: #f6fdfd !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-7 lead">Saúde e Bem estar</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: #aadee0 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-5 lead">Pratica atividade física atualmente?</td>
              <td style="background-color: #dff7f7 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-7 lead">De duas a três vezes por semana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: #8fc4c4 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-5 lead">Utiliza algum tipo de medicamento?</td>
              <td style="background-color: #f6fdfd !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-7 lead">Não</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: #aadee0 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-5 lead">Já passou por alguma cirurgia?</td>
              <td style="background-color: #dff7f7 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-7 lead">Lesão de natureza articular</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: #8fc4c4 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-5 lead">Doenças na família?</td>
              <td style="background-color: #f6fdfd !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-7 lead">Diabetes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="background-color: #aadee0 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-5 lead">Observações</td>
              <td style="background-color: #dff7f7 !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; color: #3d !important; -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact" class="col-md-7 lead">Dores musculares após atividades físicas</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: The page-break-before property is now a legacy property, replaced by break-before.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it in the style tag like this :

```
<div style="page-break-before: always;" class="row"></div>
```

Also make sure your div is block and not inline

Comment: I tried this and added display: block, but the page still doesn't break. Do I have to add it to all the divs?

Comment: Usually only on the divs you want to have a page break. Haha and I like the comment from the guy above XD. I'll try to look more into it.

Comment: I tried the tag from the guy above only on the divs I wanted a page break. Still not working

Comment: you did style="break-before:always" ?

Comment: did you put just a part of your code because you have so many useless divs its kinda hard to follow. From what i can tell those 3 divs :

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="table-scrollable"> should only be one with the 3 classes

Comment: So I should put those 3 divs : <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="portlet-body"> <div class="table-scrollable"> in the <div class="row"> and the break-before in the same div?

Comment: Yea something like that … try reducing the number of divs... you can give them more then one class. Then it will be easier to know where to put your page break

Comment: I put it all in one div, except the <div style="break-before: always">, because there was other tables inside different divs that I wanted to include in one page. So the <div class="break-before"> included two divs. Both divs are now <div class="portlet-body table-scrollable">. But the code to break the page still doesn't work

Comment: jeez rick i don't know what to say anymore.... Here's a couple of link that could help you 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-inside || https://drafts.csswg.org/css-page-3/#page-break-inside || https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#page-break-props

Comment: I'm going to check those out. But thanks a lot for the help!